# Qt How to create a QBrush using a RGB Color with QColor and change it later?

Tags: c++, qt, qcolor

At the moment I use this to create a QBrush:

```
QBrush *goldBrush = new QBrush(QColor(212,175,55));
scene->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,*goldBrush);
```

But apparently this leaks memory.

How else could you do it? I've tried this:

```
QBrush greyBrush(QColor(212,175,55));
greyBrush.setColour(QColor(120,60,55))
```

But that hasn't worked either. I want to be able to declare the brush as one colour then be able to change it.

Edit: full problem my bad.

Comment: Please give more information why the second version wouldn't work. It actually is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @ypnos Yes it does work, my bad, I did not print out the full problem. Yes I can set the colour but I cannot change it as I would have expected. Could you help? Thanks :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to change the color of a brush is via `QBrush::setColor`. The brush takes a copy of the color you specify and *not* a reference.

```
QBrush my_brush;
QColor red(Qt::red);
my_brush.setColor(red); // my_brush has its own color member internally
                        // and _not_ a reference to red
```

Maybe you are used to other programming languages like Java where basically everything is a reference. In C++ there are  [values semantics](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/).

Comment: So, should creating these brushes work: `QBrush darkBrown(QColor(83,71,65)); QBrush clickedBrown(QColor(122,83,66));` Then this if statement as a way of changing the colour, rather than chnaging the colour of one brush but using two brushes and drawing with different brushes: `if (Pressed=true) { painter->setBrush(clickedBrown); } else  {painter->setBrush(darkBrown); }`, because it doesn't either.

Comment: Your `if `check is wrong, since you always _set_ `Pressed` to `true`, `Pressed=true` is an assignment. What you want is `if (Pressed==true)`, or simpler `if (Pressed)`. A decent compiler should print a warning. You should most likely increase the warning level of the compiler you use.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set the `brush style`

```
QPainter painter(this);
QBrush brush;
QColor brushColor;
brushColor.setRgb(192 ,237, 166);
brush.setColor(brushColor);
brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and this precision because if you forget to put the style, no color appears :)